# Why does margin child element affect body element?

Tags: html, css, margin

Please can you explain to me why `body` is affected by the margin of its children ? I don't like this behaviour. In my opinion, the margin of a child `div` should be computed from the boundaries of its parent to its boundaries.

For example : 
https://jsfiddle.net/2yejm7L5/

You can see that the `div` in blue affect the margin of `body` in green, then you see the `html` background in red and I don't want that.

In my case, I don't want to edit `body` CSS properties

Comment: [Collapsing Margins](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will achieve your goal, if you modify the body css to the following:

```
body {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

/* Another technique */
remove top-margin:50px, and wrap your toto div with another div and give it padding-top:50px; as per below:

```css
html {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

#container { padding-top:50px; }

.toto {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="toto">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a trick without editing `body` properties ?

Comment: Yes, check my edited comment.